# Problem Deploying Django Site on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to deploy a Django site on AWS ElasticBeanstalk for the first time. Using the CLI, when I run "eb create" I get the following error when it begins deployment via CodeCommit:

```
Starting environment deployment via CodeCommit
ERROR: TypeError - expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

My .git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/user/repository.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[credential]
    UseHttpPath = true
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
[remote "codecommit-origin"]
    url = https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/siterepos
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/codecommit-origin/*
    pushurl = https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/siterepos
```

My .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml:

```
branch-defaults:
  main:
    environment: null
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: company
  branch: main
  default_ec2_keyname: company-eb
  default_platform: Python 3.9 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: siterepos
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application

Any ideas to get this to work?
```